# Are Sitecore's sublayout rendering stats incorrect?

Tags: performance, sitecore

The built-in Sitecore rendering stats `http://<sitename>/sitecore/admin/stats.aspx` is really helpful for identifying inefficient and slow-loading XSLT renders. Recently I've started switching to .ascx sub layouts to take advantage of the Sitecore C# API which can help improve performance when used correctly.

However, I've noticed that sub layouts (as opposed to XSLT renders) are not reported correctly on the stats page. See the screenshot below....

[image: Example sublayout stats]

I know for a fact that this sub layout takes about **1.8 seconds** to generate (I calculated this in the code-behind). Caching is turned off. I've refreshed the page 20 times to ensure I get an average. You will see that the "Avg. items" is always 0 - I can live with this - but the "Avg. time (ms)" is **less than 1ms** which is just clearly wrong.

Does anyone have any insights into this? Has anyone found a way to get it to work correctly?

Comment: I am doing a similar exercise at the moment. I've noticed that some of my ascx's report avg items whilst some dont. Have you tried running the debug and seeing what times come out of the profile/trace. I've noticed some differences.

Comment: @WesleyLomax yes I know exactly what you mean. I think the .ascx files that show avg items are ones that contain XSLTs as child renders. In other words, the avg items count is for the XSLTs, **NOT** the ascx itself. Running the debug in sitecore gives me similar results to the stats page - 0 - 10ms generation time and 0 items. It's really annoying.

Comment: XSLT is poorly understood in the Sitecore developer community.  That being said, I've definitely found that the rendering stats are not necessarily accurate.

Answer (score 3):

Judging whether a statistic is right/wrong is going to rely on understanding exactly what it is measuring.

Digging around in Sitecore.Diagnostics.Statistics using Reflector I note the following:

- Sitecore.Web.UI.Webcontrol contains a field m_timer
- This is 'started' in the BeforeRender() method and 'stopped' in the AfterRender() method
- Data from that timer is sent to Statistics.AddRenderingData() and is logged against the control

This means it is measuring the time taken to *render* the control, which for an XSLT includes the processing time for preparing all the data in it, but as much of the work of a normal ASCX is done prior to the Render-stage the statistic is much less useful.  Incorporating the Load stage in the time would inadvertently include the processing time for all child components, since the Load sequence is chained and called recursively, so that probably doesn't help much either.

I suspect there is no good way of measuring the processing time for a specific ASCX control (excluding children) without first acquiring cumulative data then post-processing the call chain and splitting the time apart.  This is the sort of thing RedGate ANTS does really well, but might not be so good if it was being executed on a live production system, given the overheads.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this @Richard. I think your point about measuring the cumulative time for child elements is valid, but in the grand scheme of things it's infinitely better than no stats at all (the current status quo). If this were the case, you would be able to quite accurately map it out on the debug/trace view built in to Sitecore.

Comment: Agreed. We use ANTS.  Perhaps a mechanism in config to turn it on/off makes sense.  I might talk to Sc dev about that, try to get it on the roadmap.